# How to make sure a player doesn't instantly re-enter a portal?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, geometry

In my game I have portals and I want to ensure you always exit next to the portal, but not in the portal as to prevent you from getting stuck in a loop. See here a diagram where the portal is the big rectangle and my player the smaller one.

[image]

I want the length of `SP`. I have the dimensions of the rectangles and the angle between them. And `SP` is the perpendiculair bisector of `BD` (and `AC`).

I think I have the math down already: I Take `A` as `(0,0)`, `B` as the vector `|AB| * e^i(pi/2 - α)` and `C` as `|AC|e^iα`. Then `S = (B+C)/2`. `SP: (x,y) = S + tB/2`. `BD: (x,y) = AB + ACt`, shift that by `(width + height)/2` of the smal rectangle to make the line go through P, which looks like `DBP: (x,y) = AB + (w, h)/2 + ACt`. Then get their intersection         `a + bt = c + ds` gives `t = (c - a + ds) / b`
`e + ft = g + hs` gives `e + f(c - a + ds) / b = g + hs`
That eventually gives `s = (f(a-c) + b(e-g))/(bh - df)`
Then fill that `s` value in `SP` and get the magnitude of the result.

In code that looks like:

```
private float Dist(CapsuleCollider2D col){
    UnityEngine.Vector2 colSz = col.size; // These are the dimensions of the smaller rect

    float apha = pi * transform.rotation.z / 180; // Degrees to radians
    Complex AB = width * Complex.Exp(Complex.ImaginaryOne * apha); // AC = e^iα
    Complex AC = height * Complex.Exp(Complex.ImaginaryOne * (apha + pi/2)); // AB = e^i(pi/2 - α)
    (Complex, Complex) BDP = (AB + new Complex(colSz.x, colSz.y)/2, AC);
    (Complex, Complex) SP = (AC/2 + AB/2, AB/2);

    // a + bt = c + ds gives t = (c - a + ds) / b
    // e + ft = g + hs gives e + f(c - a + ds) / b = g + hs
    // That eventually gives s = (f(a-c) + b(e-g))/(bh - df)

    double a = BDP.Item1.Real;
    double b = BDP.Item2.Real;
    double c = SP.Item1.Real;
    double d = SP.Item2.Real;

    double e = BDP.Item1.Imaginary;
    double f = BDP.Item2.Imaginary;
    double g = SP.Item1.Imaginary;
    double h = SP.Item2.Imaginary;

    double s = (f*(a-c) + b*(e-g))/(b*h - d*f);

    Complex difference = SP.Item2 * s;

    return (float)difference.Magnitude;
}

public void TPHere(GameObject obj, Gameobject source) {
        obj.transform.position =
            transform.localPosition // Portal pos
            + transform.rotation // Rotate by portal orientation
                * Lib.Vec2To3(obj.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity, 0).normalized //Rotate by direction of travel
                * Dist(obj.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>()) // Get the minimun distance from a rotated portal in order not to touch
                * offset; // Multiply by slider
}
```

But the code doesn't work. The numbers are way too smal. Is this even worth fixing? If so, how? Or can I better just add a tp-cooldown?

Comment: Why not just use colliders? I can image 2 cube colliders from your picture, use OnTriggerEnter/Exit to detect whether the player is in or out of the portal. If you don't touch the colliders in these callbacks, they won't get invoked in the same frame.

Comment: Why any of these calculations? You've got S you've got P, the distance between them is `(S - P).magnitude`

Comment: Is there a reason you're using complex numbers for this? Really seems like a job for vectors?

Comment: Considering 2 portals, why would you have 2 locations for triggers instead of 4? Have one location "on" the portal that sends the player somewhere, and a second location at a reasonable distance away from the first, where the player arrives. And when the player arrives on the "distant" location just set the rotation to make sure he doesn't go forward into the portal, but rather your level. Why make extra calculations when you can have dedicated locations, each for its own purpose? If you want to make sure, you can also add a small cooldown saying the Portal needs some seconds before reusing.

Comment: @bolov, the thing is that I don't have P, that is what I am calculating.

Comment: @Jay, that is possible, but these will achieve the same effect and this is easier to work out in math.

Comment: Just add an empty game object on the position of `P` in the player game object and that is your `P` without having to manually compute it.